# How to add a razor value and a string in an HTML attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I know it's simple and I am probably missing something...Assume I want to give IDs to generated controls, when my model is a list of integers:

```
@model List<Int>
...
foreach(int number in Model)
{
   <div id="box + @number"></div>
}
...
```

box + @number actually gives me : id="box + 1", "box + 2", etc.
When I want : "box1", "box2".
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try:

```
<div id="@("box"+number)"></div>
```